# Set up loop to find unique values in dataframe, sum them and add them to a new row in dataframe

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data `df` as shown below.

- `df$gene_name` contains names of genes, each row is a unique identifier.
- `df$gene_type` indicates the gene type, there are several types within this vector.
- `df$Dim1` etc contain a expression value for each gene in various biological samples.

I am trying to set up a loop (or otherwise), which add a new row to `df` summing up `df$dim.1` , `df$dim.2` etc for every unique value in `df$gene_type`. For the pictured example, the 10th row would look like,

```
df[10, 3] <- c("total", "antisense", "sum of Dim.1 values").
```

Then the code will find the next unique value in gene_type and sum `Dim.1`, `Dim.2` etc for the new `gene_type`.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of data, but rather include a minimal, reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi you want sum of Dim.1 and Dim.2 group by gene_type ?

Comment: Try `aggregate(cbind(Dim.1, Dim.2) ~ gene_type, df, sum)`

Comment: Yes, but after summing Dim.1, Dim.2 for the first gene_type I want the code to find the next gene type then sum Dim.1 , Dim.2 for that gene type and so on until there are no more gene_types.

Comment: Does my code work for you? If not, please provide minimal reproducible data and expected output.

Comment: @DarrenTsai yes it works, does exactly what I asked for.